# Is it useful to keep virtualized and host traffic physically separated?

Tags: hyper-v, vlan, local-area-network

In our old HyperV setup, I see that there's a LACP 3x aggregation for the virtual machine traffic, but for the same VLAN there's a separate cable that the host uses. Both are reachable from one another, but the LACP group has the hyperv virtual switch function enabled.

I wonder if there's a good reason why this was done or is it pure coincidence? I don't see any reason for doing it but it could be that I just don't know why.

Does this bring any advantage security/stabiltiy-wise?